# Why is it ineffective to synchronize statics of superclass in a subclass?

Tags: java, multithreading, static

I'm reading "Concurrent programming in Java Design Principles and Patterns", by Doug Lea. And he says:

> The static lock associated with each class is unrelated to that of any
> other class, including its superclasses. It is not effective to add a
> new static synchronized method in a subclass that attempts to protect
> static fields declared in a superclass. Use the explicit block version
> instead.

Why is it ineffective? Why is the explicit block version effective?

Comment: The first sentence explains why.

Comment: @Polygnome what does he mean by "not effective"? Like there's no point in it? Is he talking about redefining static synchronized methods with the same behavior in subclasses? If so then I understand.

Comment: "Not effective" means "it does not work".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For you to protect the superclass static fields, you need a common lock. If you write your class that modifies the superclass fields, and someone else writes a subclass that affects the superclass fields, you want to make sure both pieces of code reference the same lock. If they each lock on their own subclass there is no common lock and they can still interfere with each other. That is what Lea means when he says

> The static lock associated with each class is unrelated to that of any other class, including its superclasses.

Ideally we'd want to do whatever locking was needed in the class that defined the static variables and keep everything encapsulated. Apparently this ideal may not work out though, and subclasses may have to define the locking, but need to have a common policy for what lock to use.

If you create a method with `static synchronized` then that will acquire the lock on the class you defined the method on. If what you want to protect is not in that class but in the superclass, that's not what you want, you want to acquire the lock for the superclass where the fields that need protecting are declared.

The way to specify the correct superclass is to use the "explicit block syntax", like this:

```
synchronized(Superclass.class) {
    ...
}
```